# Append Multiple Jpegs from Command Line Jpeg

Tags: ubuntu, append, jpeg

I have 103 jpeg images name-001 ... name-103 that I want to append vertically. I would like to do this from the Terminal and am using Ubuntu Operating System. I have tried researching and there are plenty of options for appending vertically and horizontally; however none that show how to append multiple images with a simple line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can ImageMagick to stack images. Command will be something like:

```
magick name-???.jpg +append output.jpg
```

You should be aware that you will receive error with source images with vertical dimension bigger than 655. This is because the maximum dimensions of JPG is 65535x65535